# In Metasploit, how to use a custom exe as payload?

Tags: network, attacks, penetration-test, malware, exploit

Question was once on a mailing list but wasn't answered. I want to use a custom exe as a payload in metasploit. For example when I use exploit/multi/browser/java_atomicreferencearray and want to execute my payload.exe, how can I do that?

It is possible in SET, where you can just import a custom executable.

Is it possible in Metasploit?

Answer (score 5):

You can execute any payload file or string you like using the msfconsole with these options:

```
PAYLOADFILE The file to read the payload from
PAYLOADSTR  The string to use as a payload
ARCH        The architecture that is being targeted
PLATFORM    The platform that is being targeted
VERBOSE     Enable detailed status messages
WORKSPACE   Specify the workspace for this module
```

http://www.metasploit.com/modules/payload/generic/custom

Comment: What I did was:

`set PAYLOAD generic/custom`
`set PAYLOADFILE /var/www/install.exe`  
`generate`  
`use exploit/multi/browser/java_atomicreferencearray`  
`exploit`  

Now I get an error saying `[-] Exploit failed: Could not locate a compatible payload for Java/java`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There could be so many reasons, from incorrect syntax to wrong locations for modules etc. You need to have a read through http://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/repository documentation and have a look at other examples.