# How to execute a custom meterpreter payload?

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I've hacked a box in an internal network `10.0.0.1` and I want to use 'pass-the-hash attack' on another box `10.0.0.2` but this box has Avira anti-virus installed in, and the common payload `windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` is detectable by Avira.

So I made my own backdoor and it can bypass Avira; how can I let metasploit use it instead of meterpreter?

Comment: I googled "metasploit custom payload" and got a ton of guides, including the duplicate listed above.

Answer (score -1):

With a quick google search I found the following questions asked previously on this forum, they are not recent however may provide the answer you are looking for.

[In Metasploit, how to use a custom exe as payload?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/in-metasploit-how-to-use-a-custom-exe-as-payload)

[How can I add modules to a Payload on Metasploit](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81158/how-can-i-add-modules-to-a-payload-on-metasploit)

The following article is also catered specifically to your use case;

https://securityboulevard.com/2020/02/evading-antivirus-with-better-meterpreter-payloads/

Comment: Please do not post links as answers. Include the relevant parts of the link in your answer.